# Aligning list items down the center evenly

Tags: html, css, flexbox

So right now my list items are centered within the page, but it looks really sloppy because the dots aren't aligned with each other. I was just wondering how I could do that. Here's a code snippet:

HTML

```
<div id="list">
        <li>February 24, 1955: A Star was born. Jobs steps on the scene.</li>
        <li>1970: A friendship blossums. Steve Meets Steve Wozniac the soon to be co-founder of Apple.</li>
        <li> September 18th, 1972: Steve would graduate from highschool and enter college only to leave a semester later. He would continue to sit in on classes, most likely trying to get ideas for his soon to be built company.</li>
        <li>January 3, 1977: Apple incorporates.
</li>
        <li>December 12, 1980: Apple goes public. It's estimated that Jobs is worth 200 million at this point in his career.</li>
```

CSS:

```
#list {
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  background-color: grey;
  length: 150px;
  font-size: 22px;
  width: 100%;

}

li {


  text-align: center;

}
```

Comment: What dots? Do you mean the periods/full-stops (`.`) or the colons (`:`)? Or something else entirely?

Comment: Sorry about that. I assumed you ran the code. I mean when I display this list the unordered list dots are skewed.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need flexbox for this. Simply remove the two `text-align: center` rules that you set.

Also remove `length: 150px`; `length` an invalid property. In addition to this, `<div>` is [not a valid parent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/li) of `<li>`; you'll want `<ul>` or `<ol>`. `<menu>` is also valid, along with the obsolete tag `<dir>`.

This can be seen in the following:

```css
#list {
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  background-color: grey;
  font-size: 22px;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<ul id="list">
  <li>February 24, 1955: A Star was born. Jobs steps on the scene.</li>
  <li>1970: A friendship blossums. Steve Meets Steve Wozniac the soon to be co-founder of Apple.</li>
  <li> September 18th, 1972: Steve would graduate from highschool and enter college only to leave a semester later. He would continue to sit in on classes, most likely trying to get ideas for his soon to be built company.</li>
  <li>January 3, 1977: Apple incorporates.</li>
  <li>December 12, 1980: Apple goes public. It's estimated that Jobs is worth 200 million at this point in his career.</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: @DavidThomas -- Missed that. Fixed :)